# Translating Ashcroft and Mermin's "Second Proof" of Bloch's Theorem to Dirac's Notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

At the end of this post I attach Ashcroft and Mermin's proof of Bloch's theorem which is not essential per se (the proof using lattice symmetries is more general), but is key in being used later as a jumping off point for the nearly free electron model.

Now I am trying to translate it to Dirac's bra-ket notation, since that always helps me think in more general, coordinate-free terms (once I pull out all of the identity operators which have been tacitly inserted). Essentially, I am trying to arrive at (8.38) by beginning at the coordinate-free eigenvalue equation for $H$.

Thus I thought to write something like
$$H|\psi\rangle=\epsilon|\psi\rangle \implies \langle \mathbf{r}|H|\psi\rangle=\langle \mathbf{r}|\int \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{k}}\left(\frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m}+U\right)|\mathbf{k}\rangle\langle \mathbf{k}|\psi\rangle=\int \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{k}}\left(\frac{\hbar^2\nabla^2}{2m}+U(\mathbf{r})\right)\langle \mathbf{r}|\mathbf{k}\rangle c_\mathbf{k}=\int \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{k}}\left(\frac{\hbar^2\nabla^2}{2m}+U(\mathbf{r})\right)c_\mathbf{k}e^{i \mathbf{k} \cdot\mathbf{r}}$$

where the integration is over all of momentum (k-space up to a proportionality factor). The first term in the equation above recovers (8.36), but (8.37) I cannot seem to "find". Obviously I want something of the form (8.32), so I thought to insert completeness in coordinate space ($\mathbf{r}$), but then I have some extra $\mathbf{r}$ kets in the second term which aren't there in the first.

Any help in completing the steps which I cannot would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots. You're referring to few equations only, so please typ them with MathJax.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the fact that $U$ is periodic with the same periodicity as the lattice, which means that it can be expressed as a sum

$$U(\mathbf r)=\sum_{\mathbf G\in \mathrm{RL}}u_\mathbf G e^{i\mathbf G\cdot\mathbf r}$$

where RL is the reciprocal lattice.

Also, for what it’s worth note that since Ashcroft and Mermin are working on a torus (with Born von Karmin boundary conditions) the set of possible momenta is discrete, so the integral should be a sum. You may repeat the derivation in the continuum if you wish, but it will look slightly different than it does in the text.

Comment: Would you be able to flesh it out one more line? I can't see how to insert the various completeness identities which are needed to even get to the point you describe above.

Comment: @EE18 You don't need a completeness relation here: The equation in this answer holds due to the (lattice) periodicity of $U(r)$.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Sure, but there is clearly an integral over real space in (8.32), and that must surely arise due to the insertion of completeness somewhere.

Comment: @EE18 No, that integral is just telling you how to compute the coefficients $U_\mathbf{K}$ (which I called $u_{\mathbf G}$).   This is just a [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Exponential_form).

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it by inserting an extra complete set of momentum states.
\begin{align*}
\langle \mathbf{r}|H|\psi\rangle
&=\langle \mathbf{r}|
\int \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{k}} \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{k'}}\,|\mathbf{k'}\rangle\langle \mathbf{k'}|
\left(\frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m}+U\right)|\mathbf{k}\rangle\langle \mathbf{k}|\psi\rangle\\
&=\int \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{k}} \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{k'}}\,
\langle \mathbf{r}|\mathbf{k'}\rangle
\left(
\langle \mathbf{k'}|\frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m}|\mathbf{k}\rangle
+
\langle \mathbf{k'}|U|\mathbf{k}\rangle
\right)
\langle \mathbf{k}|\psi\rangle\,.
\end{align*}
Now, because $U$ is periodic, in the lattice, it only connects momentum states if they differ by a reciprocal lattice vector $\mathbf{G}$, i.e.
$$
\langle \mathbf{k'}|U|\mathbf{k}\rangle = \sum_{\mathbf{G}}U_{\mathbf{G}}\delta^3(\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{G}-\mathbf{k'})\,,
$$
where $U_\mathbf{G}$ is a Fourier coefficient of $U$.  We can see this in the following way. Since $\hat{U}$ is actually $U(\hat{\mathbf{r}})$, we have that
$$
\langle \mathbf{k'}|U(\hat{\mathbf{r}})|\mathbf{k}\rangle
=
\int d^3r\,\frac{e^{-i\mathbf{k}'\cdot\mathbf{r}}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}
U(\mathbf{r})
\frac{e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}
=
\int d^3r\,\frac{e^{-i(\mathbf{k}'-\mathbf{k})\cdot\mathbf{r}}}{(2\pi)^3}
U(\mathbf{r})
\,.
$$
We can write this as a sum over integrals over the primitive unit cells as
$$
\langle \mathbf{k'}|U(\hat{\mathbf{r}})|\mathbf{k}\rangle
=
\sum_{\mathbf{R}}\int_{\textrm{unit cell}}
d^3r
\,\frac{e^{-i(\mathbf{k}'-\mathbf{k})\cdot(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{R})}}{(2\pi)^3}
U(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{R})\,,
$$
since $\mathbf{R}$ indexes the primitive unit cells. (We understand this first as breaking up the integration volume into a sum over the primitive unit cells and then making the substitution $\mathbf{r}\to\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{R}$ in the integral.) Using the periodicity of the function $U$ and pulling out factors independent of $\mathbf{r}$, this becomes
$$
\langle \mathbf{k'}|\hat{U}|\mathbf{k}\rangle
=
\left(
\frac{V_{\textrm{uc}}}{(2\pi)^3}
\sum_{\mathbf{R}}
e^{-i(\mathbf{k}'-\mathbf{k})\cdot\mathbf{R}}
\right)
\left(
\frac{1}{V_{\textrm{uc}}}\int_{\textrm{uc}}
d^3r
\,e^{-i(\mathbf{k}'-\mathbf{k})\cdot\mathbf{r}}
U(\mathbf{r})
\right)
\,.
$$
Finally$-$and this is the part we sort of pull a rabbit out of a hat, a rabbit otherwise known as the *Poisson resummation formula*$-$the first factor is exactly equal to
$$
\sum_{\mathbf{G}}\delta^{3}(\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{G}-\mathbf{k}')\,,
$$
where $\mathbf{G}$ is a reciprocal lattice vector, and so, defining
$$
U_{\mathbf{G}} = \frac{1}{V_{\textrm{uc}}}\int_{\textrm{uc}}
d^3r
\,e^{-i\mathbf{G}\cdot\mathbf{r}}
U(\mathbf{r})\,,
$$
we get exactly the result shown above.

Then
\begin{align*}
\langle \mathbf{r}|H|\psi\rangle
&=\int \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{k}} \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{k'}}\,
\langle \mathbf{r}|\mathbf{k'}\rangle
\left(
\frac{k^2}{2m}\delta^3(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k'})
+
\sum_{\mathbf{G}}U_{\mathbf{G}}\delta^3(\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{G}-\mathbf{k'})
\right)
\langle \mathbf{k}|\psi\rangle
\\
&=
\int \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{k}}\,
\langle \mathbf{r}|\mathbf{k}\rangle
\frac{k^2}{2m}
\langle \mathbf{k}|\psi\rangle
+
\sum_{\mathbf{G}}\int \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{k}}\,
\langle \mathbf{r}|\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{G}\rangle
U_\mathbf{G}
\langle \mathbf{k}|\psi\rangle
\\
&=
\int \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{k}}\,
\frac{e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}
\frac{k^2}{2m}
\tilde{\psi}(\mathbf{k})
+
\sum_{\mathbf{G}}\int \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{k}}\,
\frac{e^{i(\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{G})\cdot\mathbf{r}}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}
U_\mathbf{G}
\tilde{\psi}(\mathbf{k})
\\
&=
\int \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{k}}\,
\frac{e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}
\frac{k^2}{2m}
\tilde{\psi}(\mathbf{k})
+
\int \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{k}}\,
\frac{e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}
\sum_{\mathbf{G}}
U_\mathbf{G}
\tilde{\psi}(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{G})
\\
&=
\int \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{k}}\,
\frac{e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}
\left(
\frac{k^2}{2m}
\tilde{\psi}(\mathbf{k})
+
\sum_{\mathbf{G}}
U_\mathbf{G}
\tilde{\psi}(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{G})
\right)\,.
\end{align*}
where in the last step we have used a change of variables $\mathbf{k}\to\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{G}$. We have also notated the Fourier transform of $\psi$ as $\tilde{\psi}$.

Comment: As far as I see, the procedure in the question is correct.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker yeah, I was just going through the derivation in the other direction to show why it was wrong and realized that it was fine.  It's just not the most direct way of getting there. I'll amend the post. I could add a quick addendum evaluating the matrix element of $U$ that gets us the Fourier coefficient, but it's essentially the same as what is done in the linked image.

Comment: Hi march. I'm just back here as I read through AM again. Can you explain by any chance how you obtained $\langle \mathbf{k'}|U|\mathbf{k}\rangle = U_{\mathbf{G}}\delta^3(\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{G}-\mathbf{k'})\,,$ in particular, where $U$ is actually an operator $\hat{U}(\hat{\textbf{r}})$?

Comment: My suspicion is that it should instead be $ \langle \mathbf{k'}|U|\mathbf{k}\rangle = \sum_\boldsymbol{G}U_{\mathbf{G}}\delta^3(\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{G}-\mathbf{k'})$ to account for all of possible RL vectors (of which the two vectors could have as the difference) but I am unsure how to derive that.

Comment: @EE18.  You're absolutely right about the summation; I've fixed it and added a section about proving that identity about the delta-function. It involves what's called the *Poisson resummation formula*, recast in terms of delta functions as the *Dirac comb identity*. I've actually never seen the general proof for an arbitrary Bravais lattice, and in one dimension, it requires some machinery from distribution theory.

Comment: I see, thank you @march! Do you think things are at all easier if we've normalized the $| \textbf{k} \rangle$ in a box so that the delta functions become Kronecker deltas?

Comment: @EE18.  They are easier to *prove*, but the argument is the same: the "Poisson resummation formula" basically takes the same form in this case, with $(2\pi)^3$ replaced by $L^3$ and the delta function becoming the corresponding Kronecker-delta.

Comment: I see, thank you. Would you be able to point to a resource on this summation formula? Wikipedia's article is completely impenetrable to me.

Comment: @EE18 It's probably worth looking at the article for the [Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) instead, but to be honest, this is just one of those things I think it's worth just *knowing*.  To get a feel for why it works (at least in 1D), it could be worth just plotting $\sum_{n=-N}^Ne^{2\pi n/t}$ as a function of $t$ for increasing choices of $N$ (say, in *Mathematica*) and see that you get something that looks like a Dirac comb.  On the other hand, [I found this](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9780470949955.app1), which gives a heuristic derivation.

Answer (score 1):

You can work it backwards:

$$\sum_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{K}}U_\mathbf{K}e^{i(\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{K})\mathbf r}c_\mathbf{k}=\sum_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{K}}U_\mathbf{K}e^{i\mathbf{K}\mathbf r}\langle \mathbf r|\mathbf{k}\rangle\langle \mathbf{k}|\psi\rangle=\sum_{\mathbf{K}}U_\mathbf{K}e^{i\mathbf{K}\mathbf r}\psi(\mathbf r)=\sum_{\mathbf{K}}U_\mathbf{K}\langle \mathbf r|\mathbf{K}\rangle\psi(\mathbf r)$$
$$=\int dr'\sum_\mathbf{K} U(\mathbf r')\langle \mathbf{K}|\mathbf r'\rangle \langle \mathbf r'|\mathbf{K}\rangle\psi(\mathbf r)=\int d^3r' U(\mathbf r')\langle \mathbf r|\mathbf r'\rangle\psi(\mathbf r) =U(\mathbf r)\psi(\mathbf r)$$